# Serialize datetime to JSON

Tags: python, django

How do I get `DateTimeField` from MySQL in Django in JSON format? I got an error when I executed the code

> Date.time cannot be serialized in json

(data holds a lot of values)

```py
data = json.dumps(data)
```

But this was fixed by adding

```py
ALL_data = serializers.serialize("json", data, ensure_ascii=False)
```

But now I get `'str' object has no attribute '_meta'`.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

[**DjangoJSONEncoder**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/serialization/#djangojsonencoder) solved my problem.

```
import json
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
data = json.dumps(data, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

Comment: What would you use for `json.loads()` ?

Answer (score 5):

Django's serializers are only meant to be used on query sets; you will have to find a different way to solve your problem, such as converting the `datetime` to something else first.

Comment: [If you wish to store more advanced data types including datetime and Decimal in JSON backed sessions, you will need to write a custom serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#write-your-own-serializer)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you see an error message of the form `... object has no attribute '_meta'` that is a clear-cut sign that a method was expecting a queryset but got something else. In this particular situation, serializers.serialize must have a queryset for its second argument. You can't use a list, dictionary, etc., and definitely not a string.

Where is `data` being set. Check to make sure it's being assigned a true queryset. You might also want to post more of your code, if you're still having issues. It's difficult to diagnose the problem much more, out of context.