# How to overcome the serialization error in datatime?

Tags: python, django, riak

Hi friends I have data in dict format as shown.,

```
data = {'x':'some data', 'last_login': datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 6, 8, 41, 59, tzinfo=<UTC>), ...}
```

Now when I am trying to store this data in riak I am getting type error and its raising an exeption.

```
TypeError: datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 6, 8, 41, 59, tzinfo=<UTC>) is not JSON serializable
```

Can anyone tell me whats causing this and how to fix this?

Comment: convert it to string. use `strftime` .

Comment: @PriyankPatel no other way other than converting it to a string because I am storing large amounts of data and for each data I need to change that.

Comment: Hi @MartijnPieters, it is not a duplicate and I want to convert lastlogin or datetime object so that it won't cause any error or exception

Comment: Refer : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583401/serialize-datetime-to-json-in-django` as suggested by @Martijn .

Comment: @user2936254: have you *tried* using the method in the other answers? You have datetime objects in your data, use the Django JSON serializer.

Comment: Hi all, for my code I am just checking if data is having datetime object and changing it to string and then storing, this solved the problem.