# How do I send an array of objects from a django class based view to my index.html file?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, fullcalendar

**The Goal:**

I want to use FullCalendar(https://fullcalendar.io/) to display event objects from my database. FullCalendar accepts an array of event objects as a property.

**The Problem I'm having:**

I can send context data back to the template with the event objects but as far as I know I can only interact with the data using Django's template tagging system. *EDIT: When I replace the hardcoded array with ptoHistory I receive the following error in the chrome console:

> jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: ptoHistory is not
>   defined
>       at HTMLDocument. ((index):141)
>       at j (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
>       at k (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)

*index.html:*

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

//ACCESSING THE CONTEXT DATA LIKE THIS WORKS BUT I CAN'T USE ptoHistory IN MY FULLCALLENDAR SCRIPT 
{% for history in ptoHistory %}
 <li>{{obj.leave_type}}</li>
{% endfor %}

<div class="container">
  <div id="calendar">
    <!-- Calendar is injected here -->
  </div>

<!----------------------- SCRIPTS ----------------------------->
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView:'month',
    editable: true,
    // MY ARRAY OF OBJECTS WILL REPLACE THIS HARDCODED ARRAY
    events: [
      {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2017-01-12',
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2017-01-13T10:30:26',
        end: '2014-06-13T12:30:00'
      },
    ],


  });

});

</script>


{% endblock content%}
```

IndexView.py:

```
class IndexView(FormView):
    template_name = 'accounts/index.html'
    form_class = PtoRequestForm
    success_url = 'login/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(IndexView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['ptoHistory'] = PtoHistory.objects.all()
        print(context['ptoHistory'])
        return context
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't understand where the issue is. You are already passing data to the view correctly, what else are you asking?

Comment: @dabadaba I updated the question. Please re-read "The problem I'm having"

Comment: So basically you want to use data sent from the view in your scripts, right? I think you can start by looking at how JS is seeing that data, and format it correctly either in the Django side or the JS side to match what your calendar plugin expects. I have encountered the same scenario before and I recommend you format and build up your data in the view rather than in your scripts, as you have more control over it since it's where it comes from after all.

Comment: That's correct. Even if I build the data the way I want it in the view and send it over to the html file through context data I still run into the problem that I can't use the data outside of the django template tagging system.

Comment: But you can convert arrays, dictionaries and primitive data to JS variables. Just use `var jsData = {{ djangoData }}` or `"{{ djangoData }}"` and decode it. I also recommend you use the filter `{{ djangoData|js }}` to convert it to a JSON string. There's also `|safe` to escape data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, it won't work. Django template system is able to process python objects because they are executed already before the template is finished rendering.

You could still assign python list in javascript, though, but not with python objects but json string. The solution is basically compose for only what you need in the views using `values()` then . I don't know what fields do you need for `PtoHistory`, but you could do:

```
# views.py
import json
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    ptoHistory = json.dumps(list(PtoHistory.objects.values()))
    # or do this if you only need several fields' value
    # ptoHistory = json.dumps(list(PtoHistory.objects.values('field1', 'field2')))
    context['ptoHistory'] = ptoHistory

    return context

// in javascript
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView:'month',
    editable: true,
    var histories = {{ ptoHistory|safe }};
```

Comment: For some of the values I have datetime fields which are not json serializable. I get an error when I try to serialize them.

Comment: Simple, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583401/serialize-datetime-to-json-in-django

Comment: Thanks Shang that worked. I also have a foreign key field to a user object that says can't be serialized. Is there any way I can serialize that too?

Comment: If you do it manually it could be `PtoHistory.objects.values('fk__field1', 'fk_field2')`, otherwise check django doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/serialization/. Google is your friend.