# How to use default datetime serialization in Django REST Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've got a Django REST Framework serializer containing the following:

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class ThingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    last_changed = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_last_changed(self, instance: Thing) -> str:
        log_entry = LogEntry.objects.get_for_object(instance).latest()

        representation: str = serializers.DateTimeField('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').to_representation(log_entry.timestamp)
        return representation
```

This is problematic because if the datetime formatting ever changes it will be different to all the other `datetime`s. I want to **reuse the code path which DRF uses to serialize other `datetime` fields.**

What I've tried so far:

- The only [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5781657/96588) which looked relevant doesn't actually produce the same result as DRF (it includes milliseconds, which DRF does not), presumably because it's using the Django rather than DRF serializer.
- `rest_framework.serializers.DateTimeField().to_representation(log_entry.timestamp)`, `rest_framework.fields.DateTimeField().to_representation(log_entry.timestamp)` and `rest_framework.fields.DateTimeField(format=api_settings.DATETIME_FORMAT).to_representation(log_entry.timestamp)` don't work either; they produce strings with microsecond accuracy. I've verified with a debugger that DRF calls the latter when serializing other fields, so I can't understand why it produces a different result in my case.
- `LogEntry.timestamp` is declared as a `django.db.DateTimeField`, but if I try something like `LogEntry.timestamp.to_representation(log_entry.timestamp)` it fails badly:

  > AttributeError: 'DeferredAttribute' object has no attribute 'to_representation'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking a look through the source of DRF, the interesting stuff is happening in `rest_framework/fields.py`.

In particular, all of the formatting stuff is happening directly in the `DateTimeField.to_representation` method.

You have a couple of ways of replicating DRF's behaviour.

---

First, you could just not pass a format at all. DRF should use its default if you don't explicitly supply a format.

```
representation: str = serializers.DateTimeField().to_representation(log_entry.timestamp)
```

---

Alternatively, keep doing what you're doing, but explicitly pass the format string from DRF's `api_settings.DATETIME_FORMAT`. This might feel less magical, but honestly it's probably more brittle to API changes in the future.

This might look like:

```
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings
...
representation: str = serializers.DateTimeField(api_settings.DATETIME_FORMAT).to_representation(log_entry.timestamp)
```

---

However, given that you attempted the first and it failed, we need to look a bit deeper!

The default DateFormat for DRF is `ISO_8601`, which has the [following code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L1236) in it:

```
value = value.isoformat()
if value.endswith('+00:00'):
    value = value[:-6] + 'Z'
    return value
```

That is, it effectively just leans on the python `isoformat` function.

`isoformat` will format differently **if the value has microseconds or not**.

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat), `isoformat` will:

> Return a string representing the date and time in ISO 8601 format, YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.ffffff or, if microsecond is 0, YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

In this case, the solution is to explicitly set the microseconds to **zero** in the timestamp. There are a couple of ways to do this, but we can switch to a Unix timestamp, clip to seconds, and back again

```
ts = int(log_entry.timestamp)
representation: str = serializers.DateTimeField().to_representation(ts)
```

or keep using the DateTime object directly, which will have better timezone handling:

```
representation: str = serializers.DateTimeField().to_representation(
        logentry.replace(microsecond=0)
    )
```

Comment: I tried the first one already, and it produced a different format from all my other datetime fields…

Comment: You're right, the milliseconds change the formatting! Frig!