# Object of type date is not JSON serializable, getting error in django templates

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to dumps data to json in views.py. And send to django templates for javascript but getting error.
models.py

```
class resource(models.Model):
 title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
 size=models.CharField( max_length=20, default="")
 desc=models.TextField(default="")
 file=models.FileField(default="", blank=True)
 url= models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True)
 varient=models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
 Brand = models.ForeignKey(brand,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
 Model = models.ForeignKey(model,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
 Categories = models.ForeignKey(category,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
 update_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
 paymentvarified=models.BooleanField(default=False)
 slug=models.SlugField(default="", unique=True, blank=True)
 Tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
```

views.py

```
 data={
    'limitjsondata':json.dumps(list(resource.objects.values())),
    'get_pro':get_pro,
    'Resource':Resource,
    'pro_member':pro_members,
    }
return render(request, 'firmApp/download.html', data)
```

When I run server and go to specic page it through an error.

```
Object of type date is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583401/serialize-datetime-to-json

The accepted answer here should provide you with the answer you need.



Side note:  The "Django"/pythonic way of writing a class is to have each word in the classname be capitalized.  The attributes, or fields in the case of Django, should all be lowercase and snake_case.

Comment: you should write your custom serializer for the resource model and convert datetime to str so that json can serialize it properly. There is no concept of date in json so you are facing this error.